# I built a tool as an answer to a common problem on SO and was banned for promoting myself

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, banning, self-promotion

It's been a few months since this happened, but I saw it took some of my motivation for answering questions away and I don't want that to happen.

---

I saw that people need an equivalent of MutationObservers (new browser/JS feature) for browsers not supporting them. To be able to help them I created a library for that based on a more supported technology. And I put a link to it with a description of what it supports in a question I found first.

I then kept on finding more questions that could benefit from my answer, so I posted it in a few more places. Then it turned out that I credited the wrong person for discovering a technique I used in the lib, so I had to update all the answers at once.

(The person got quite angry and might have flagged my answer, we talked more via e-mail and apologized to each other for the misunderstanding)

I got punished for self-promotion and all my answers with this lib were deleted. The moderator who did it didn't reply to my explanation in the ban-textarea (no idea what it's called)

I still believe my answers were useful and I didn't benefit from posting them in any way (except ~100 reputation points at most).

Now the only mention of this lib is in someone else's answer: [Script that watch elements and change text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591757/script-that-watch-elements-and-change-text/15591845#15591845)

One of my deleted answers is here: [Mutation Observer is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21600892) [edit: I updated the answer. Check the history]

---

Did I really do something wrong? What am I missing? Can those answers be brought back with some editing?

Comment: Did you read [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497) yet?

Comment: I scanned it and I'm digging in right now. In my answers I actually did state that the code is my own and I did not profit from it.

Comment: @naugtur Next time read through the self promotion rules *before* you go around promoting yourself.  Also, if you're banned for promoting yourself inappropriately, take the time to at least read through the relevant rules before you post on meta about it.

Comment: I did read through the rules quite some time ago. I'm talking about the thread mentioned above. Now that I'm finish I can say I was aware of the policy created in that thread and I did my best to comply.

Comment: It is very rare that significantly different questions can be answered well with the exact same content, so please flag duplicates appropriately next time and make sure your answers are complete.

Comment: @false The content was not the same. The questions were not duplicates, but they all needed to extend browser support for detecting DOM insertions. I agree the answers were incomplete in some cases. And it is possible that multiple questions have the same answer. I am the first person ever to get the silver jquery-mobile badge and I did it by answering questions that were different but originated from one of the 3 most common problems with jqm.

Comment: btw. There is no point in promoting my lib for my own interest as it will become obsolete once IE10 goes away. It's only useful now and it will never go big, as it only serves a really narrow use-case.

Comment: The linked answer looked awfully self-promotional to me. At least include a sample of how the library solves the problem, if not the relevant portion of the library itself. I probably would have flagged it had I come across it.

Comment: After reading everything here I edited the answer. What do you think now?

Comment: @naugtur That looks a lot better. If you could include a code sample that utilizes your library it would be perfect.'

Comment: ITT: A lot of stock answers reproduced without engaging with the question or situation. I suspect @naugtur is barking up the wrong tree if he wants nuance or sense from the meta hivemind.

Comment: @naugtur thanks for sharing. thank you for creating the library and also for having the humility to understand where your approach could have been improved. a valuable resource like the SO community, and that it hasn't been destroyed by actual spammers, marketers, profiteers verges on the miraculous.

Comment: Thanks for making the library. My guess is that for most of the question not the whole library but only parts of it would have been beneficial. Instead of "forcing" (recommending/promoting) a whole library it might have been better to put the relevant parts of the code here in each case and only link for further information to the library. Just my 2cent.

Comment: Answer shouldn't have been deleted. Thanks for bringing this to the communities attention. It was noble of you. I hope your answers are brought back and unbanned.

Comment: and still after all the discussion, we are left with many questions that have lost the usefulness of possible fixes. We have burnt the books with the knowledge in them. I can't see why @naugtur would bother to include code samples to all those questions again, and fight to have each one reinstated. Luckily I don't work with web so this is largely an academic issue to me.

Comment: I'm willing to do that because the answers might still be useful to someone for a year or so. The hardest thing now is to find all the questions. My deleted answers aren't listed anywhere and I have no tools for tracking down all of them.

Comment: Months later, and I didn't fix other answers. Not being able to find them easily was too discouraging. Opened a discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289071/feature-request-tools-for-filtering-my-answers-list

Comment: I thought your answers were fine. I've committed worse crimes of self-promotion on SO, mostly a few years ago, and seem to have got away with it. Linking to a maintained GitHub repository for a solution to a common problem has to be better than making static copies or near-copies of other answers. I voted to undelete your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie but apparently since it was deleted by a moderator it cannot be undone.

Comment: I wanted to undelete them, I was ready to fix the content (as you see linked) but never got any response from moderators except the bad-cop talk above. I believe the browsers that insertionQuery was a fix for are almost dead anyway...

Answer (score 138, accepted):

[your deleted answer didn't attempt to answer the question beyond providing a link](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21600892/1), which is why it was considered self-promotion/spam. The answer said you had a library and linked off-site.

To avoid self-promotion and provide a useful answer you'd need to start by answering the question with relevant code inline. It's generally ok if you show an example of your library in action to give explanation as to why it's actually useful/necessary.

Additionally, as an author, it's even better to pull any necessary code from the library so as to show how someone could solve the problem *without* using your library.

After you've done all of that it **then** becomes acceptable to post a link with a strong disclaimer that you're the author of the library and possibly additional explanation of why it's relevant.

Comment: +1 Valid points. I did answer the question imho, but that's not important here. I agree the answer was a bit too general. If I posted all the code, it'd be a lot... Especially to cover the cross-browser compatibility. I could post code fixing the issue using my lib in the solution. Would that be enough?

Comment: @naugtur, the deleted answer as I see it amounts to a link-only answer. If that link were a dud, the answer provides no value to someone looking for a solution to the problem. You don't need to do a code dump, but a brief rehashing of the relevant bits that show the techniques used would have made a significant difference in that example specifically.

Comment: @naugtur  Yes that would be enough.  For all practical purposes you can treat your own library as you would treat any other library that you might suggest.  Just be sure that your answer is actually an answer to the question

Comment: I find answers that suggest a different library to solve a problem without including how said library solves it to be very annoying. Though, i agree that would be an acceptable minimum.

Comment: @KevinB, I agree and would add that the exception is when it takes an entire library/plugin to solve the issue. Sometimes it's best to basically say "there are too many issues that need to be addressed to solve this seemingly simple problem in less than 1k lines of code here's a link to a common library that many people have contributed to to make this go much more smoothly". But even with that, hashing over the major points is still useful.

Comment: Yep a simple code example on how to do it with a disclaimer and link to library would suffice in my opinion. It would help in preventing this spamming.

Comment: Here's a great example of doing it right. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21600892/400654

Comment: Oh. I didn't even notice that answer was from this OP. :)

Comment: :) That's the one I fixed after getting feedback in here. I just added an example of the lib usage too. Now I'll edit all the other answers to address questions more directly.

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to post a single SO Q/A post like "Q. How do I work around the bug _____ in IE10?"  where you self-answer and show usage of your library, with off-site link; and then you can link to that post when answering other posts .  If the site rules permit that, IDK.

Comment: It does, Matt - it's called a canonical answer. The question would be closed as a duplicate because even though it's a different problem than other people, the answer is the same.