# Feature request: tools for filtering my answers list

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

It is hard to search through my answers to find those that I'd like to update (eg. new feature added to browsers that changes some answers, should be easy to find them by tags) 
Browsing through all my answers is very simplistic.

*Let's look at a particular case:
I had ~10 answers deleted as self-promotion, see:
[I built a tool as an answer to a common problem on SO and was banned for promoting myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263018/i-built-a-tool-as-an-answer-to-a-common-problem-on-so-and-was-banned-for-promoti)
I wanted to fix all the answers like I did with the one discussed in the thread, but it's hard to click through all the pages of answers on my profile page. *

Being able to filter my answers (by words in content, tags set on question, answer state - accepted, deleted, downvoted) would help me keep them up to date.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't seem to include deleted answers.

Comment: Hmm, true. But that sounds like a really rare use case and I don't really see SE letting us search through our deleted stuff. But I see the problem.

Comment: I remember accessing them from the profile page when found manually in the list

Comment: @naugtur _"I remember accessing them from the profile page ..."_ Here they are: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/173077 As a trusted user you might apply more sophisticated queries using the [SE DataExplorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already exists, in a way, if you strike the "must work for deleted answers" requirement. That one I don't really see happening on SE, given how little they support discovering deleted content even if it's your own.

Try e.g.

> `populate is:answer [javascript] user:me`

in search, for example, to search for all your answers in the JavaScript tag that contain the word "populate".

Comment: This would work, but  it doesn't cover all the cases, most importantly - doesn't find deleted answers, while they can be found in the list in my profile as far as I remember.

Comment: @naugtur Working on your deleted answers you should target them specifically. There
s a _[deleted recent answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/173077)_ link on your profile page to access them (Note anyone, that the link should only work for the owner of these answers).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that! It's a pity that my answers aren't that recent anymore though.