# Did the site policy regarding link-to-tool answers change?

Tags: support, declined-flags, moderation, moderators

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45503272/3002139) as VLQ:

[image]

...which was declined by a moderator stating:

> I don't think it's reasonable for a moderator to delete this outright. The comment you left prompting them to expand the answer is more appropriate. Probably doesn't merit a VLQ flag.

Based on posts like [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/3002139), I was under the impression that answers that have no content besides the name of some tool should be removed, and I flagged 100s of answers like this in the past. All three [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16935383) that saw that post also agreed with me.

So did we change site policy regarding answers that just recommend some tool? Is there a Meta for that?

Or was this simply an incorrect moderator action?

Comment: That does look a lot like a link-only answer to me. I mean, it could be an appropriate answer to a tool request question...which shouldn't be very appropriate.

Comment: *new mods, new rulez...*

Comment: That's not how I interpret [the last official guidance we were given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Yes, it would be nice if you could motivate them to transform it into a *better* answer, but it looks like an answer as it stands to me. It names a library and says what it does, which is clearly applicable to the question. This isn't exactly the same as "link-only with no content". The tutorial links are just bonus. Also similar to: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284397.

Comment: @CodyGray But what about the possibility that the link will get obsolete in future?

Comment: @CodyGray This isn't about the links to the tutorials. I have been flagging answers that just recommend a tool or library without demonstrating how it solves the problem for a while now, under the impression that deleting them is community consensus. If it isn't (anymore), I'd like a Meta explicitly stating it that I can refer to.

Comment: Sure, that's always a possibility, but that's why you *name the library*. That way, someone can fix the link if it disappears. I resuscitated at least two answers with dead links to libraries today.

Comment: I have not see anything on this issue remotely resembling community consensus. We have discussions about what to do with these types of answers *ad nauseum*. Nothing ever gets resolved with any clarity.

Comment: @CodyGray If not community consensus, deleting answers like this seemed to be at least common practice among moderators and the LQQ reviewers. As I said, I literally flagged 100s of answers like this, and today was the very first time such a flag was declined, against the vote of reviewers, too.

Comment: Well, nobody told me, obviously. I see nothing in psubsee's answer that I disagree with. I just don't see the answer you flagged as being "link-only". It contains more than a link, and even if the link were invalid, the library suggestion seems like it would constitute an answer by the apple/castle guidance. Honestly, I flagged some stuff like this a long time ago, and I got all of those flags rejected and was told here on Meta that isn't how we do things, so I stopped fighting it and modified my standards. So for you to say that this is precedent is...well, quite new and surprising to me.

Comment: Just naming their preferred library is what spammers do. We want to distinguish real answers from those somehow - that is, by demonstrating _how_ to use said library.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not saying it's link only, I flagged it because I thought (and think) that answers that just recommend some tool or library are VLQ, too.

Comment: @BaummitAugen While that answer may be low quality, it isn't _very_ low quality. It can be fixed. If you read the VLQ flag, it mentions the post being unlikely to be saved through edits. This answer can be saved through edits. So the VLQ flag was wrong.

Comment: I find that *even more surprising*. All of the official and semi-official (i.e., written by moderators) guidance that I can ever remember reading on Meta has basically said that VLQ is only to be used for posts where there is no chance of salvaging them, where they are just complete garbage. [This answer is only one example of what I'm referring to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269726/366904). [Here's another one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/366904). They are all over the place here, if you search for them.

Comment: @Kendra how do you intend editors to fix that? They can't write code on answerer's behalf.

Comment: @JohnDvorak If all that's "missing" is an example of how to use the tool, it would be trivial to edit in said example. As it stands, however, the answer does answer the question. It is poor quality, sure, but it's not absolute trash, and it can be improved through editing. Especially since there are tutorials linked from that answer. Very trivial.

Comment: While I think this is low quality and down votes and delete votes would be OK I do not think it is flag worthy.

Comment: @John No one has to write any code. Recalling [psubsee's answer that Baum linked in the original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/3002139), all that has to done to make tool recommendations acceptable in an answer is to add an explanation of how the tool solves the problem. Anyone can do that.

Comment: Trivial to edit in said example? No. Such things require experience with said library - something the answerer should bring, not editors. And copying code from the documentation - if the library even has such a thing - might not be kosher from the licencing standpoint.

Comment: Also @CodyGray: *"Honestly, I flagged some stuff like this a long time ago, and I got all of those flags rejected and was told here on Meta that isn't how we do things, so I stopped fighting it and modified my standards."* Do you have a link to that Meta?

Comment: @CodyGray I still can't see how "anyone can add an explanation how the tool solves the problem"

Comment: I wasn't *personally* told. I've never actually started a constructive discussion about flags. I just troll other people's discussions. ;-) What I was referring to were all the advice that I mentioned in my last comment about what VLQ meant, and which types of posts it should be applied to. [Robert Harvey's "I interpret the flag as 'gibberish'"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260816/366904) always sticks in my mind. So I find it strange for you to be telling me that has changed. I had no idea.

Comment: Please show me on an example, fix the answer in question to include an explanation of how to use the library. Without putting words into the answerer's mouth. I can't see how to do it without using some example code.

Comment: @John There is nothing wrong with putting words in the answerer's mouth. Many constructive edits do that. You keep talking about "copying code". Code has nothing to do with any of this. The standard for a good answer isn't whether it gives me teh codez. The guidance is, does it *explain how the library would solve the problem*. You don't need code to explain things.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to do things. Please show me how an ordinary editor with no experience with the library could fix that. (Apologies if I sound defensive - I just want to clear up our understanding)

Comment: @CodyGray The thing you linked in your last comment seems to mostly deal with questions, which by their nature are more naturally dealt with via down and close votes I guess. Anyways, when I saw that declined flag, I was at least as surprised as you appear to be now. *"So I find it strange for you to be telling me that has changed."* From my point of view, that declined flag means something has changed, the status quo as I saw it was "flag and delete that stuff".

Comment: As for nothing being wrong with putting things in the answerer's mouth - I mean, how do you fix that without being rejected by the common edit reviewer for changing too much?

Comment: VLQ or NAA by now has no distinct meaning, to tell the truth gibberish is flagged with abusive flag (if OP has no other meaningful contribution), as far as "Download this tool it solves the problem",  I would follow Bill's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16935383)

Comment: To quote myself from SOCVR just now: "Spammers tell you to use their thing without saying how. We require real answers to be different."

Comment: I saw a report on that post by Natty (my memory say so) and when reading the text content (other than link), I think it is not VLQ. the person added some information so it is not VLQ.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Plenty of spammers also tell you how to use their thing though...It's on the unusual side, sure, but certainly not what distinguishes spam from not spam.

Comment: Do you have an example of that? I would think that spammers showing off their products kinda gives away the fact their product just isn't as good as they claim it to be.

Comment: FWIW, I [distilled this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) from several years worth of meta discussion a while back; one of those might be what you were thinking of, @John

Comment: Another issue I considered here is that, if a moderator deletes an answer, it *cannot* be restored by the user who posted it, *even if* they were to follow our advice and edit it into shape. I think that should either factor into our policies surrounding this somehow, or a feature request should be raised that removes that restriction in certain cases or changes it so mods can put an answer "on hold". What's great about the *community* deleting it (aside from the pressure being off me, of course) is that the answer can still be *undeleted* by the original poster after it is edited.

Comment: @CodyGray General advice I've seen for that case was "Edit, then raise a flag for undeletion". This seems, again, more likely to work than waiting for 3 users randomly noticing that some deleted answer was improved. The OP cannot override 20k delvotes himself afaik.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It might indeed be what I'm thinking of. Let's see if I remember to request the policy to be what we thought it was...

Answer (score 20):

Almost 30 comments here, an hour of discussion, and I'm both the first person to answer *and* the first person to downvote the answer being discussed?

Y'all are slacking.

Anyway... "Very low quality" is subjective, one of those "I know it when I see it" things. I wouldn't consider that answer VLQ either, but some might and I don't particularly fault you for it.

There are, as usual, multiple problems here:

1. The answer doesn't answer the question.
2. The question looks broader than it should.

The asker is using the Jansson JSON parser, and running into a problem with it. He doesn't mention this until the second paragraph, and NONE of the other answers attempt to address it either.

I don't rightly know if this question is salvageable, but if you want to get rid of that answer it's probably worth making it a bit more obvious that it doesn't answer the question.

**Update:** I can't help but gloat that the answer has now been deleted, by normal users, which they could conveniently do *because it scored less than zero*. Use your votes!

Comment: So were the reviewers and mods that marked my previous flags as helpful all wrong? Don't get me wrong, I'm not obsessing about that one declined flag, I want to understand why what used to be right (apparently) is now wrong, and what I should do in the future.

Comment: I haven't looked at your previous flags, @Baum; just this one. Unless you raised multiple flags on *this answer*, you'll have to consider whether there were effective differences between this and previously-flagged answers.

Comment: So... was flagging _this_ answer inappropriate? Even though it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Shog9 There is no obvious difference for me, which is why I ask in the first place. I thought: Recommends library, does not demonstrate how it solves the problem -> flag. Which has served me well, I had a non-declined streak of like 4.7k flags until yesterday. (That one declined comment flag was on me, I was wrong.)

Comment: Did you look at the other answers on that question, @Baum?

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, I did. I saw a bunch of upvoted answers, [trying to solve the actual problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17514915/3002139) or [presenting an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17515023/3002139). I also checked that the question is not a resource request, for which I don't raise flags, but vote to close the question instead. Nothing I saw led me to believe this answer should not be flagged.

Comment: You flagged one answer that recommended an alternative but not the other?

Comment: @Shog9 The other answer suggesting an alternative is way more extensive than *"Use boost."*, unlike the one I flagged.

Comment: @Shog9 the other answer that recommended an alternative showed how to use the alternative. The answer in question didn't - and that's why it got flagged.

Comment: Also, regarding your update: 2 of the votes were cast from review, and were thus results of my flag. The last one was probably Meta effect. I don't think it's terribly likely 3 20k users come across a new answer to an old question like that to cast their vote by chance.

Comment: It doesn't bother you that the example is irrelevant to the question, @John?

Comment: What do you mean? I may be missing something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: The question is about the problems someone is having using Jansson to parse a string containing a JSON object. The answer is about using Boost to load a JSON file. It is every bit as irrelevant as the answer that was just deleted, just longer. The asker even responded to it by going back and editing the question to specify "no Boost"!

Comment: Oh, true. Now, regarding the general policy this question asks for ...

Comment: I thought that answers recommending tools were required to demonstrate how to use a tool? If not, when did that change?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not taking the bait on that, @John - as I said, VLQ is subjective. Folks always want a guarantee that if they flag something that matches a ridiculously vague pattern those flags are gonna be acted on in the exact same way 99.999% of the time - that's not going to happen until we replace all moderators with a few simple regular expressions. To be clear, I think both answers are crap and I downvoted both of them.

Comment: Fine, maybe other answers are bad, too, but I still need general advice regarding tool/lib recommendation answer. Do they need to demonstrate how it solves the problem or not? Alternatively, what makes this answer better than the 100s I've flagged before?

Comment: So... are you explicitly saying that a general policy won't and can't exist because even if a general policy is proposed on meta, moderators are welcome to ignore that? That isn't good....

Comment: @JohnDvorak There is no *requirement* for that.  A lot of people have said that answers that only recommend a tool aren't good answers (an entirely sensible position to have).  That doesn't make them deletion worthy, nor does it make it an official policy.  If you think an answer is a bad answer, downvote it.

Comment: Of course not, @John. There are lots of general policies. One declined flag isn't evidence to the contrary, it just means a moderator disagreed with one specific flag on one specific post.

Comment: @JohnDvorak The point is that the official policy is not, "flag answers as VLQ that suggest a tool", the official policy is, "flag answers of no redeeming value, that are complete garbage and are unsalvageable, as VLQ".  You might think that this answer meets that criteria; the moderator disagreed.  If you try to create shorthands like, "all answers suggesting a tool are always unsalvageable and have no redeeming value" then you'll frequently (or occasionally, depending on how good your heuristic is) run into problems when those heuristics turn out to have exceptions.

Comment: In my defense, I intentionally avoided answering the question. For starters, I can't possibly answer whether the site policy has changed, which is what's being asked here. Furthermore, I'm not wedded to the decision that I made, so I don't want to sound like I'm arguing it was correct. (I agree the flagged answer was bad; that's not the same as insta-delete.) I'm really quite interested in seeing if we can establish anything approaching a community consensus here, but I suspect that's impossible. Still, I'm curious about the discrepancy between my understanding and Baum's flag history.

Comment: If it's not a requirement, that raises two new questions, though. Why did I think it was a requirement, and could it be made so? I'm pretty sure it should be, given the reasons I've already stated.

Comment: Those are good questions, @John. The first one you should ask yourself; the last one you should ask the site.

Comment: @CodyGray it might look like we're testing the waters, you're doing fine. No defense needed.

Comment: In my defense, I only answered this question [because rene was afraid of accidentally agreeing with you](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6247050#6247050), @Cody. So you could still post that comment as an answer if you like. Also, this response is totally not a ruse to get you to spend more time reading chat.

Comment: @John Relevant meta posts: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266194), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263018), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289074). The criteria to look at here would be 1) make sure that the question is unequivocally not a resource request (edit to make that clearer if need be), then 2) make sure that the answer unequivocally does not appear to be an attempt to answer the question once all of the link markup has been removed. If there is any doubt in either of those criteria, then it is a risk of a declined flag to flag it.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being annoying, but this does not answer my question yet. You are writing stuff about the specific Q/A, but unless you can tell me why this answer is better than the ones I flagged before, that does nothing to explain why the metrics I use to judge recommendation answers, enforced by a lot of flags marked helpful, failed me here. As it stands, my question remains: Was I wrong all the time flagging answers because the recommended some off-site resource without demonstrating how it solves the problem? If so, why did I get away with it that long? If not, did the rules change?

Comment: That being said, @Cody is always welcome to do spend more time reading the chat and replying to it 

Comment: @Cody I would really appreciate an answer from you, I'm part of the crazy group that actively hunt down problems on SO. Whether we should do this or not is another question (if SO was scaling better, we could probably avoid), however what is certain is that we need metrics when we review more then 400 answers/questions/comments x day. To sum up, set metrics and we will follow'em filling your queue with correct stuff.

Comment: *and do note that we have notice the **excellent work** you been doing all day responding to flags*

Comment: *Why did I think it was a requirement* @JohnDvorak I think you're thinking of the requirement that answers not be link-only answers. It's probably also been said that a tool recommendation should explain how it solves the problem in order to be considered a *good* answer.

Comment: Out of all the flag types, VLQ seems by far the most likely to be declined. I used one once (incorrectly, and realised my mistake) and have yet to find another situation where I feel like a VLQ flag won't be immediately declined. But maybe that's just a totally random feeling I have with no connection to reality ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Clonkex it entirely depends on how you usually interact with Stack Overflow. It is entirely likely that you may never see a post that qualifies for the VLQ flag, while others may see hundreds every day. This depends on the tags you frequent, and how you frequent them.

Comment: I [posted stats on that a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-the-very-low-quality-flag-if-not-can-we-remove-i/340905#340905), @Clonkex. VLQ has a lower success-rate than some other flags, but not particularly treacherous.

Comment: That's a false dichotomy, @Baum. Your previous flags were deemed correct by the moderators who handled them; this one flag, a moderator disagreed. If I had that kind of success rate in *anything* I'd be pretty confident; I really don't see anything here that'd make me question your judgement (apart from, as I said, you should probably be more willing to downvote answers). The "rules" I'm aware of regarding product recommendations are mostly in regard to *questions* not answers, save those concerning spam - so there's nothing to discuss on that front.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok, thank you for your time and explanation!

Comment: @Shog9 That whole post is very interesting, especially the top "other" flags; that list explains a lot of the current flag types we have (`Not an answer` being an obvious one, but also the whole off-topic section).